# What is the name of the show that involves a wish granting cat with a weakness to water?

Tags: onegai-samia-don

I remember when I was a kid watched an anime about a wizard cat. I think he was yellow and fat and each episode he made wishes come true hmmm... maybe for a bunch of kids?

He also has a weakness, the water, he hated it and I remember in one episode he touched the water and felt really sick and start to bleed by one of his mustache hairs.

That's all I remember,oh well, and it was a really funny animation. Anyone knows?

**==UPDATE==**

I remember some other stuff too: He has a pointed hat, as a magician. Maybe black or blue, maybe has some stars? (I'm not so sure about that last point) and each time he started his magic, he dances and spins around with a lot of effects, kind of like any magical anime girl power.

I live in Chile, South America and it was not very popular between my friends (at least I've asked a few times and nobody remembers), but it must have been broadcasted in the '90.

And the last thing "I think" it was anime, I mean, I remember kind of anime drawing style and the ending with credits writing and song language unknown for me at that age.

Comment: shot in the dark - doraemon?

Comment: When were you a kid? (It'll help narrow the list down.) @ton.yeung I think Doraemon is only afraid of robotic mice.

Comment: @ton.yeung It wasn't doraemon, but similar

Comment: @coleopterist I've added some more facts about that show

Comment: No magic. But how about [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084064/) (not anime)?

Comment: @coleopterist hmmm, nope, I don't think so. Actually, maybe is not even a cat, but I remember him like that, yellow and the size like a fat cat. He could walk too

Comment: lol your description makes me think of the tv serie:  Sabrina the Teenage Witch (animated version) although the cat is black cant handle water, can use magic as he also teaches sabrina.

Comment: @Dimitrimx haha, yeah, close enough, but the anime I watched it was about 20 years ago, maybe a little bit more :P

Comment: well, maybe its just me but I have the feeling it was more of a cartoon then a anime. but if you say +-20 years ago it might be worthwhile to check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_in_the_United_States    its all the anime released from 1960 till now in the united states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last I found it! Actually it was not a cat, but the rest of my description fits. The name is "Please! Psammea-don" (おねがい!サミアどん Onegai! Samia-don?)
[image]

It seems that it only was broadcast in Latin America, France, Quebec and the Arab World [as noted by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onegai!_Samia-don) and [it was also never released in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Children_and_It#Adaptations), so maybe that's the reason why nobody here knew this animation.

PS: I really loved [the ending](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCpMA2C4SjE)

Answer (score 2):

From what you explain I just remember Rocky Rackat(Pokonyan) ! 
When I was a kid I watched it from TV and know it as Mio Mio! ^_^

This picture is that cat?
[image]

Comment: Hmmm, nope, sorry :/